# ARM Assembly Language: Will this conditional statement branch to label "dest"?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to figure out whether the following piece of code will allow the assembler to branch to the label 'dest'.

```
LDR  R1, =value
LDR  R2, [R1]
ADDS R2, R2, #200
STR  R2, [R1]
BEQ  dest
```

Where value initially contains 0xFFFFFF38. I understand the 's' at the end of the ADD instruction will add the decimal value 200 and R2, and place the result to R2, while also seting the APSR flags, but I'm not necessarily sure what is being compared in the BEQ statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Many assembly languages have a `BEQ`-type instruction which often follows some comparison instruction like `CMP` (hence the "equal").

But, since a comparison is often an "subtract but throw away the result" operation, `BEQ` will simply branch if the *zero* flag is set.

In other words, what you tend to see are things like (in some mythical pseudo-assembler code):

```
; basically: for (reg1 = 0; reg1 != reg2; reg1++)
    load reg1, 0
startloop:
    cmp  reg1, reg2   ; pretend subtract reg1 - reg2
    beq  endloop      ; zero flag set means they were equal
    : :
    inc  reg1
    bra  startloop
endloop:
```

However, you're not limited to *just* comparisons, anything that sets the relevant flag could be used, such as:

```
    load reg1, [memaddr]  ; loading zero from memory
    dec  reg3             ; decrementing if we go 1 -> 0
```

---

In your particular case, `STR` does not actually change the condition flags, it's the `ADDS` which affects the branch (in fact, it's the `S` suffix that specifies this since a regular `ADD` does not).

So, bottom line, if the result of your `ADDS R2, R2, #200` (the final result placed into `R2`) is zero, the branch will be taken.

That will indeed be the case if the initial value is `FFFFFF38h` and you add `200` (`C8h`):

```
   FFFFFF38
         C8 +
   --------
(1)00000000 =
```